# Maria DB входит под root без пароля, а подключиться через localhost не получается?

Tags: mariadb

Устанавливал mariaDB (***mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.38-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2***
)по [инструкции](https://losst.ru/ustanovka-mariadb-v-ubuntu-18-04):

```
sudo apt install mariadb-server mariadb-client
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

Всё установилось. Но не получается настроить вход **root** пользователя по **localhost**.

> Could not connect: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Через терминал заходит с командой **sudo mysql -u root -p** и **sudo mysql**.

Как дать доступ по **localhost**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 вариант решения проблемы описан [тут](https://www.linux.org.ru/forum/admin/13554233). Решение:

```
# mysql -u root
MariaDB [(none)]> use mysql;
Database changed
MariaDB [mysql]> update user set password=PASSWORD("my-new-cool-password") where User='root';
MariaDB [mysql]> flush privileges;
MariaDB [mysql]> update user set plugin='' where User='root';
MariaDB [mysql]> quit;
Bye
# systemctl restart mariadb
```

*Для новичков, таких как я, обращайте внимание на ответы БД. После каждой операции изменения данных в БД, должна выводиться информация об затронутых и изменённых строках. Если команда успешна, то будет **изменена** 1 строка!*

> **UPD** 
>   Ещё один вариант решения проблемы  [www.digitalocean.com](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-reset-your-mysql-or-mariadb-root-password).

Answer (score 0):

Root не имеет доступа к БД по умолчанию из целей безопасности.
[См. ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35748657/9099581)

Возможно, имеет смысл создать базу данных и пользователя, который будет иметь все привилегии для этой базы данных:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> create database test1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> grant all privileges on `test1`.* to 'username'@'localhost' identified by 'password';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> flush privileges;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

P.S. если пароль не требуется устанавливать, можно обойтись без `identified by 'password'`.